# Error when displaying JSON data in PHP due to different fields

Tags: php, json, parsing, field

I am trying to display a list in PHP from a JSON API feed, and the fields keep changing from one array to the next.

Can someone help with a solution to get the display right

Json script, you will see that the JSON has both uniqueId and mac fields that change in each instance under the clientId

```
    {
  "searchMeta": {
    "maxResults": 100,
    "sourceId": "6e5c1d5d-d84b-4b64-9d2c-a32b8c9f7174",
    "iso8601Timestamps": true,
    "sourceType": "VENUE",
    "endTimestamp": 1444952156,
    "startTimestamp": 1444952056
  },
  "ranges": [
    {
      "clients": [
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "6c:19:8f:bf:47:e9"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -93.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "Kn04"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -75.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "58:6d:8f:75:95:0e"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -86.2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "44:d9:e7:21:e0:de"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -25.8
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:26"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -47
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "68:72:51:10:e7:29"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -72.3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "a4:ee:57:2e:ac:bd"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -95
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "CQos"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -64.1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "86:8f:c2:8f:c3:20"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -68.4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "32:91:8f:6c:2e:f4"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "30:91:8f:6c:2e:f3"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -86.9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "30:91:8f:43:ca:49"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -87
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "1d:8b:90:7b:20:9c"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -102.5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "mac": "38:2c:4a:5c:b6:a0"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -76.7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "clientId": {
            "uniqueId": "ECgg"
          },
          "rssis": [
            {
              "sourceId": "zR1L3",
              "value": -59.5
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "timestamp": "2015-10-15T23:35:00+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then the code to read and display it is

```
    $json = json_decode($response,true);
    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach($json['ranges'] as $range){
        foreach($range['clients'] as $client)
        foreach($client['clientId'] as $client1)

            foreach($client['rssis'] as $data){

        $output .= "<h4>".$range['timestamp']."</h4>";

        $output .= "<li>Source ID: ".$data["sourceId"]."</li>";
        $output .= "<li>Value in dB: ".$data["value"]."</li>";
    }}

    $output .= "</ul>";


if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $output;
}
```

it then displays on the webpage leaving out the uniqueId or the mac fields. I need the line that will display either of these please?

> 2015-10-13T04:26:00+00:00
>
> Source ID: zR1L3 Value in dB: -89.2
>
> 2015-10-13T04:26:00+00:00
>
> Source ID: zR1L3 Value in dB: -98.8
>
> 2015-10-13T04:26:00+00:00
>
> Source ID: zR1L3 Value in dB: -74.6

Thanks for the answer below, now I get the following.

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:11:00+00:00

mac : f4:b7:e2:31:65:8f

sourceId : zR1L3

value : -95

2015-10-16T10:12:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:12:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:12:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:12:00+00:00

2015-10-16T10:12:00+00:00

mac : f4:b7:e2:31:65:8f

sourceId : zR1L3

value : -95

2015-10-16T10:13:00+00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting what exactly you are asking. If i have understood correctly, you want to access few fields from json encoded array.

Try this

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);
foreach($json->ranges as $row){
        foreach($row->clients as $row1)
            echo $row->timestamp."<br>";
            foreach($row1->clientId as $key => $val){
                echo $key." ==== ". $val."<br>";
            }
            foreach($row1->rssis as $row2){
                foreach($row2 as $key => $val){
                    echo $key." ==== ". $val."<br>";
                }
            }     
    }
```

I could not get timestamp from what you have posted as json array.

Comment: Hi Niranjen It is sort of working, the timestamp is further down the JSON. the foreach($json->ranges as $row) I have had to change to foreach($json[ranges] as $row) as the -> did not work. Could you help me with an update in the new format? Thanks Rob

Comment: Give me some time, i will check that, and will come up with updated answer.

Comment: I just added where the timestamp is to the JSON to help. Thank you so much.

Comment: The way I needed it displayed was Timestamp: \n  mac or unique ID \n Source ID: \n Value: \n.   Hope that helps. Thank you so much for your help too.

Comment: add one complete json response... it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Niranjan, please find the full JSON now. Thanks again. Rob

Comment: I have updated my answer to get time stamp. check now.

Comment: thanks, and the format change please with the square brackets []? that I think is screwing with the formatting.

Comment: `[]` is used to access arrays. and `->` used to access objects.

Comment: cool. Thanks. I have added a comment to show the output. Its not putting them in order though.